# Some textfields not showing

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Basicly I'm adding dynamicaly sprites and textfields, which i populate from xml, in for loop. I'm building sort of table, so for every sprite, I'm adding new data in textfields. I've loaded xml and passed data to 2 xmllists, both traced and doing fine... Later on I add data from xmllist to array which then I'm looping in for loop.

Problem is that from 1st xmllist, 6 out of 7 textfields are visible, 1 can't be found nowhere :/ from the 2nd xmllist only 1 out of 4 are visible...

I've tried everything, tracing them returns that they are visible, on good position, filled with text, contrasted color from background...

If anyone have any idea what's bugging me, I would appreciate any help...

Thank You!

Mario

PS: here is the part probably causing the problems..

```
for(mojbroj = 0; mojbroj < dohvatiosamih2; mojbroj++)
{
    if(mojbroj % 2)
    {
        lista.graphics.beginFill(0xdddddd);
        lista.graphics.drawRect(150, prenesi + (mojbroj + 1) * 17, 200, 17);
        lista.graphics.endFill();

    }
    else 
    {
        lista.graphics.beginFill(0xbbbbbb);
        lista.graphics.drawRect(150, prenesi + (mojbroj + 1) * 17, 200, 17);
        lista.graphics.endFill();

    }

    poljeIme.x = 150;
    poljeIme.y = prenesi + (mojbroj + 1) *17;
    poljeIme.height = 17;
    poljeIme.defaultTextFormat = ovo_fmt;
    poljeIme.text = textArray3[mojbroj];
    /*  
    poljeIme.background = true;
    poljeIme.backgroundColor = 0xff0000;
    */
    poljeKvadrat.x = 305;
    poljeKvadrat.y = prenesi + (mojbroj + 1) * 17;
    poljeKvadrat.height = 17;
    poljeKvadrat.defaultTextFormat = ovo_fmt;
    poljeKvadrat.text = textArray4[mojbroj];

    addChild(lista);
    addChild(poljeIme);
    addChild(poljeKvadrat);
    // textArray.push(poljeIme);
    trace(poljeIme.y + "   "+  poljeIme.x);

}
```

Comment: Hi Mario, unfortunately there is little data to reproduce your problem, but you might want to check for these common pitfall: 1. Check that you're not getting empty strings from the xml nodes you're using on text fields that do not display; 2. If you're using embedded fonts, check that the embedding works and the .embedFonts property is set to true on the textfield. HTH

Comment: thank you for your answer. 

embedFonts are not used in those particular textfields, arrays are getting data into strings from xml nodes.

the problem is that inside the for loop all textfields are generated, and only last one is not visible...

Comment: Ok, I'm still guessing here, but you set the y for both textfields to prenesi + (mojbroj + 1) * 17. I presume prenesi is an offset and 17 is the text height. Does your list have a header or something ? Otherwise I don't understand why you use (mojbroj + 1). Also, for the MovieClip containing your list, do you have a mask applied or are you using the scrollRect property ? Could you isolate your code into a snippet that could be easily reproduced/tested ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do `addChild(lista);` in each iteration, but I assume you defined it before your your `for` iteration and it holds the background with colored rows. Maybe `lista` is ontop of the last text field. Try make `lista.alpha = 0.5` and see if your TextField shines thru.